# How do I name individual functions/graphs when plotting in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple graphs on my plot and want to label them so it is easier to distinguish?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "label them".

Comment: Name them, so their names show up in the plot.

Comment: Name as in [`title()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) or name as in [`xlabel()` and `ylabel()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html) or name as in [`legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)? There's probably a question that addresses all these cases on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the `legend()` function in the Matplotlib.pyplot library. The easiest way to use this function is to give it a list of strings which are the names of each plot.

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
y2 = [0, 2, 4, 6]

plt.figure()
plt.axes()
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.legend(['Plot 1', 'Plot 2'])

plt.show()
```

Which produces the following plot.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTPuG.png)